# what resolutions does my laptop support?

Tags: resolution, hdmi

My laptop supports 2560×1600 resolution,

I need know does it also support 2560×1080 resolution perfectly?

I will buying "LG 25UM65-P Ultra-Wide IPS Monitor" but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it should be able to support the common resolutions below the max resolution you said. However, without much info to go off of, its a bit difficult to give a more precise answer. Some information that would help would be if you could tell use the Laptop's manufacturer and the model number.

Comment: thank you, I sent an email to my Laptop's manufacturer and waiting. my Laptop's model is "Lenovo ThinkPad E531".

Comment: I forgot about going to your display properties. Usually you can right click the desktop and click display settings. From there you should either see where you can modify the resolution via a slider bar, or you should be able to easily find where to modify it. The slider will tell you all the detected supported resolutions of your built in display, and if you use the external display port, it will detect the resolutions supported for external monitors which sometimes can be higher resolutions than the built in display.